# Best way to take screenshot in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screen, screenshot, shortcode

**Fast screenshot**

How to easily take screenshot of my screen in windows 10?

I would like to have option to select a part of my screen to take the screenshot.

Comment: Feel sorry for those people that added negative vote...

Comment: Yeah, this should have been moved to SuperUser instead of closed. How odd.

Comment: This is a good one! should not be closed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I accidently found a easy way to take screenshot of my screen in windows 10.

#### Just hold Windows Logo Key + Shift Key + S

[image]

Than you can select what part of the screen you want to take the screenshot.
This will copy of a selected part to your clipboard and than you can simply past it in Paint, photoshop or any image app you want.

Thanks @Abhi
There are many other ways to do this as well:
**1. Snipping Tool** : Start > All Programs > Windows Accessories > Snipping Tool.

**2. Windows Key + Print Screen** : Windows Key + PrtScn.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar This wasn't actually a question to answer. I answered my question to let everyone else know about this method I accidently found in windows 10. By the way 3 of your methods does not work and only 1 and 2 works. Anyway I'm going to give you vote up and please give vote up as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can take screensort by following ways:

**1. Snipping Tool** : Start > All Programs > Windows Accessories > Snipping Tool.

**2. Windows Key + Print Screen** : Windows Key + PrtScn.

**3. Windows Key + H** : Windows Key + H

**4. Alt + Print Screen** : Alt + PrtScn.

**5. Windows Logo + Volume Down** :hold down the Windows Logo touch button at the bottom of your Surface screen

Answer (score 0):

Or you can easily use Windows key+fn+printscreen keys